# change a shape background color for a button and put an onclick change for it in android

Tags: android

I have an android app and I have some buttons which are a game's button and by each click on each button, it's background color would change. and I want that when the button pressed (just on click) , the stroke color change.
**but both of them together is not possible with my code.**

here is one of my buttons xml code:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_left_buttom"
    android:background="@drawable/circlebtns"
    android:onClick="LBCl" />
```

circlebtns is a xml file which is a selector:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/circle_backgrounds_level3_clicked" android:state_pressed="true"/>
 <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/circle_backgrounds_level3_clicked" android:state_focused="true"/>
 <!-- focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/circle_backgrounds_level3"/>
 <!-- default -->

</selector>
```

and its drawable shapes are:
circle_backgrounds_level3:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="@color/yellow"/>
    <stroke 
        android:width="6dp"
        android:color="@color/white"
        />
    <corners 
        android:topLeftRadius="80sp"
        android:topRightRadius="80sp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="80sp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="80sp"/>

    <padding android:left="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:bottom="0dp"/>

</shape>
```

and circle_backround_level3_clicked is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <stroke 
        android:width="4dp"
        android:color="@color/creamText"
        />
    <corners 
        android:topLeftRadius="80sp"
        android:topRightRadius="80sp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="80sp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="80sp"/>

    <padding android:left="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:bottom="0dp"/>

</shape>
```

I change the button's color after each click on it by using this code in the activity class :

```
GradientDrawable bgShape1 = (GradientDrawable) myButton.getBackground();
    bgShape1.setColor( Color.parseColor("#EDF229"));
```

if I don't use a selector for my button's background, everything is okay; but I want that when user press the button, it's stroke changes.
when I run the app I get this error:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
 ComponentInfo{com.example.game/com.example.game.Level3}: 
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable
 cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable
```

thanks for your time.

Comment: Exactly what the error says: the background drawable is a StateListDrawable (defined by <selector> in your XML) and cannot be cast to another type. If you need to manually manage the background color at run time, don't use a state list.

Comment: aha, but I need to have a change when buttons pressed. how to do it while I need to manage the background color too?

Comment: You could set a touch listener on the view, but that gets complicated. You could probably get away with just doing `((GradientDrawable) myButton.getBackground().mutate().getCurrent().mutate()).setColor(...)`.

Comment: your code solved the error, now by each click on the button the stroke will change **but the background color changes too**, and when I release the button the background color would change to it's previous one. any way to  just change the shape stroke on pressing? I want that **when pressing :** _the stroke change and the previous color be the backgroung color_; **and when released :** _the new background appear_.